# Set All Children to Largest Child's Height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am nearly done creating a jQuery slideshow. It is working perfectly except for the fact that the height of the slideshow is always the height of the first displayed slide rather than the biggest slide in the slideshow which screws up the slideshow. You can see this displayed here: http://www.renegademagsu.com . I found some jQuery solutions to the issue on StackOverflow but none seem to be working for me.

I need to loop through the every .slideshow element on the page, then loop through each of the currently selected slideshow's slides, find the largest height, and apply it to all the slides in that slideshow. Here's what I coded that I thought would work:

```
var maxheight = 0;
$('.slideshow').each(function() {
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        maxheight = ($(this).height() > maxheight ? $(this).height() : maxheight);
        console.log(maxheight);
    })
    $(this).children().height(maxheight);
    console.log('Final:' + maxheight);
    maxheight = 0;
})
```

But this just screwed up the slideshow altogether, which can be seen in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B4rqz/

If anyone could help me figure this out, I'd greatly appreciate it. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="post-container">
    <div class="post-content">
                    <div class="post-meta">
            <h3>Date: May 9, 2014 | Author: Noelle Devoe | <a href="http://renegademagsu.com/?p=195/#comments"><span class="dsq-postid" rel="195 http://renegademagsu.com/?p=195">0 Comments</span></a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="post">
            <a href="http://renegademagsu.com/?p=195">
                <h1>6 Moments That Denzel Washington was a bad ass</h1>
            </a>
                                                                                            <div class="slideshow">
                                                        <div class="slideContainer">
                    <div class="slide">
                      <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://renegademagsu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/training-day.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slideInfo">
                        <h1>1. Training Day</h1>
                        <p class="slideCaption">
                            Who could forget Denzel’s Academy Award winning role as Detective Alonzo Harris, the corrupt and rogue narcotics officer who plays by his own rules.  A memorable scene is when Alonzo and the rookie cop Jake, stop two guys from raping a 14-year-old girl. While Jake chooses to arrest them, Alonzo grabs one of the men, puts a knife to his throat, and then points 2 guns at his crouch, threatening to shoot him.  Instead of shooting he punches him and says, “Man I’m thirsty, I could use a beer.”                              </p>
                        <p class="slideCredit">
                            <a href="http://roley.tumblr.com/post/8472254874/told-me-to-suck-your-dick-is-that-what-you" target="_blank">roley.tumblr.com</a>                            </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--slideInfo end-->
                    <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>
                <!--slideContainer end-->
                 <!--end if each if-->
                                                        <div class="slideContainer">
                    <div class="slide">
                      <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://renegademagsu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/man-on-fire.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slideInfo">
                        <h1>2. Man on Fire</h1>
                        <p class="slideCaption">
                            If you want to learn about revenge, just watch Denzel in action in this movie after kidnappers try to take little Dakota Fanning. Denzel, her bodyguard, gets ahold of a corrupt cop who he needs answers from, and interrogates him by sticking a detonator up his rectum, threatening to blow the cop up if he doesn’t get information. However, when he finally gets the answers he’s looking for, Denzel detonates the bomb anyway and walks away from the explosion in slow motion. Total bad ass move.                             </p>
                        <p class="slideCredit">
                            <a href="http://www.thefancarpet.com/uploaded_assets/images/gallery/1498/Man_On_Fire_18347_Medium.jpg" target="_blank">The Fan Carpet</a>                            </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--slideInfo end-->
                    <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>
                <!--slideContainer end-->
                 <!--end if each if-->
                                                        <div class="slideContainer">
                    <div class="slide">
                      <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://renegademagsu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/american-gangster.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slideInfo">
                        <h1>3. American Gangster</h1>
                        <p class="slideCaption">
                            Denzel plays the notorious gangster, Frank Lucas, who kills a man who doesn’t pay him the money he owes.  Without hesitation, Lucas kills the man in the stree                             </p>
                        <p class="slideCredit">
                            <a href="http://www.dvdbeaver.com/film2/DVDReviews42/american%20gangster%20blu-ray/HF7Y9005_american_gangster_blu-ray.jpg" target="_blank">DVD Beaver</a>                            </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--slideInfo end-->
                    <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>
                <!--slideContainer end-->
                 <!--end if each if-->
                                                        <div class="slideContainer">
                    <div class="slide">
                      <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://renegademagsu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/safe-house.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slideInfo">
                        <h1>4. Safe House</h1>
                        <p class="slideCaption">
                            What do you do when you’re a fugitive and a CIA agent is looking after you?  Just follow Denzel’s bad ass steps in this one scene.  After Ryan Reynolds’ character has arrested Denzel’s character, he takes him to an arena where a soccer game is taking place in order to get weapons out of a locker. While in a crowd outside the arena, Denzel manages to trick the stadium security into believing he’s being kidnapped. They not only set him free, but then arrest Ryan Reyonlds. Denzel then effortlessly waltzes right out of the stadium. No sweat for a bad ass.                            </p>
                        <p class="slideCredit">
                            <a href="http://www.hbo.com/movies/safe-house" target="_blank">HBO</a>                            </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--slideInfo end-->
                    <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>
                <!--slideContainer end-->
                 <!--end if each if-->
                                                        <div class="slideContainer">
                    <div class="slide">
                      <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://renegademagsu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/malcolm-x.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slideInfo">
                        <h1>5. Malcolm X</h1>
                        <p class="slideCaption">
                            Denzel’s portrayal of Malcolm X was the role that most thought would win him an Oscar. In one scene, Malcolm and other members of the Nation of Islam demand the release of one of their fellow Muslims from jail by crowding the street outside of the building. After succeeding in this, Malcolm raises his hand and signals for his men to leave. With flick of his wrist, about one hundred protesters turn in unison and march away, as if a general had commanded them. Even a white cop notices his influence and says, “That’s too much power for a n***er to have.” If Malcolm X wasn’t bad ass enough, Denzel playing him just sweetened the deal.                             </p>
                        <p class="slideCredit">
                            <a href="http://www.popjavascript:void(0);cornreel.com/jpgimg/x%20004.png" target="_blank">Popcorn Reel</a>                            </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--slideInfo end-->
                    <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>
                <!--slideContainer end-->
                 <!--end if each if-->
                                                        <div class="slideContainer">
                    <div class="slide">
                      <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://renegademagsu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/remember-the-titans.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slideInfo">
                        <h1>6. Remember the Titans</h1>
                        <p class="slideCaption">
                            No one can forget Denzel’s role as coach of a newly integrated high school football team in 1970s Virginia. Even though this is one of Denzel’s small bad ass roles, you have to admit, Coach Boone was scary enough to intimate anyone into doing 100 push ups.                            </p>
                        <p class="slideCredit">
                            <a href="http://www.monologuedb.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/denzel-washington-coach-herman-boone-remember-the-titans.jpg" target="_blank">MonologueDB</a>                            </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--slideInfo end-->
                    <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>
                <!--slideContainer end-->
                 <!--end if each if-->
                 <!--end each-->
            </div>
            <!--slideshow end-->
            <div class="slideNav">
                <div class="prevSlide">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="slideCount"></div>
                <div class="nextSlide">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i>
```

CSS:

```
body {
     background-color: #000;
     font-family:'Source Sans Pro', Arial;
     font-size: 18px;
 }

b, strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

 .container {
     width: 960px;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }

 header {
     width: 100%;
     height: 135px;
 }

 .logo {
     width: 260px;
     height: 135px;
     float: left;
 }

 nav {
     width: 685px;
     height: 135px;
     padding-left:15px;
     float: left;
 }

 nav ul li {
     float: left;
     line-height: 135px;
     position: relative;
 }

 nav ul li a {
     font-size: 24px;
     color: white;
     background-color: black;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-right: 20px;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     display: block;
 }

 nav ul li a:hover {
     text-decoration: underline;
 }

 nav ul ul {
     width: 200px;
     height: 50px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 85px;
     left: 0;
     display: none;
     z-index: 1000;
 }

 nav ul ul li {
     float: none;
     line-height: 50px;
 }

 nav ul ul li a {
     font-weight: regular;
     font-size: 20px;
 }

 nav ul li:hover ul {
     display: block;
 }

 .search {
     width: 260px;
     height: 135px;
     float: left;
 }

 section {
     width: 640px;
     float: left;
 }

 .post-container {
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
 }

 .post-image img {
     max-width: 100%;
     z-index: 1;
 }

 .post-content {
     position: relative;
     left: 30px;
     width: 580px;
     z-index: 2;
 }

 .thumbnail-positioning {
     bottom: 110px;
     margin-bottom: -110px;
 }

 .post-content p {
     line-height: 22px;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
 }

 .post-content img {
     max-width: 100%;
 }
 .post-meta h3 {
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 12px;
     color: white;
     margin-bottom: 3px;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 }
 .post-meta a {
     color: white;
     text-decoration: underline;
     font-weight: bold;
 }

 .post {
     background-color: white;
     color: black;
     padding: 15px;
 }

 .post ol {
     list-style-type: none;
     list-style-type: decimal !ie;
     /*IE 7- hack*/
     margin: 0;
     margin-left: 3em;
     padding: 0;
     counter-reset: li-counter;
 }

 .post ol > li {
     position: relative;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     padding-left: 0.5em;
     min-height: 3em;
     border-left: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
 }

 .post ol > li:before {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: -1em;
     width: 0.8em;
     font-size: 3em;
     line-height: 1;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: right;
     color: #464646;
     content: counter(li-counter);
     counter-increment: li-counter;
 }

 .post p:last-child {
     margin-bottom: 0 !important;
 }

 .post h1 {
     font-size: 34px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-bottom: 7px;
 }

 .post a {
     color: black;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 .page {
     width: 550px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     background-color: white;
     padding: 15px;
 }

 .page p {
     line-height: 22px;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
 }

 .page h1 {
     font-size: 34px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     border-bottom: 1px solid black;
     margin-bottom: 7px;
 }

 .leftimage {
     margin: 0 10px 2px -50px;
     float: left;
 }

 .leftcaption {
     margin: 3px 0 0 80px;
     font-style: italic;
     font-size: 11px;
     width: 220px;
 }

 .leftimage img {
     max-width: 300px;
 }

 .rightimage {
     margin: 0 -50px 2px 10px;
     float: right;
 }

 .rightcaption {
     margin: 3px 80px 0 0;
     font-style: italic;
     font-size: 11px;
     width: 220px;
 }

 .rightimage img {
     max-width: 300px;
 }

 aside {
     width: 290px;
     float: right;
 }

 aside h1 {
     color: white;
     font-size: 28px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid white;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 aside .widget {
     margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

 aside ul li {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 aside ul li a {
     font-size: 19px;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 aside ul li a:hover {
     font-size: 19px;
     color: black;
     background-color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

input[type=text]{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    color:#505358;
    font-size: 18px;
}

 footer {
     width: 100%;
 }

 footer .widget {
     width: 300px;
     float: left;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     padding-right: 20px;
 }

 footer h1 {
     color: white;
     font-size: 28px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid white;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 footer ul li a {
     font-size: 19px;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 footer ul li a:hover {
     font-size: 19px;
     color: black;
     background-color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 .alignleft {
     float: left;
     margin: 0 10px 2px -45px;
 }

 .alignright {
     float: right;
     margin: 0 -45px 2px 10px;
 }

 .fix {
     clear: both;
 }

/************SLIDESHOW************/

.slideshow {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
.slideContainer {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

.slideshow .slideContainer:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}

.slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.slideMiddle {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.slide img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.slideInfo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.slideNav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.prevSlide {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
}
.nextSlide {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
.slideCount {
    width: 23.3%;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    left:40%;
}
.slideCredit {
    width: 100%;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.slideCredit a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.slideCount').each(function(){
var text='1/'+$(this).parents('div.post-container').find('.slideContainer').length
$(this).text(text)
})

var maxheight = 0;
$('.slideshow').each(function() {
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        maxheight = ($(this).height() > maxheight ? $(this).height() : maxheight);
        console.log(maxheight);
    })
    $(this).children().height(maxheight);
    console.log('Final:' + maxheight);
    maxheight = 0;
})

$('.nextSlide').show()  
$('.prevSlide').hide()

$('div.nextSlide').click(function (e){
var count=parseInt($(this).siblings('.slideCount').text())
var slideshow=$(this).parents('div.post-container').find('.slideshow')
var slides = $(slideshow).children().length;
if(count===slides){
  e.preventDefault()
    }else{
  count++
  $(this).parents('div.post-container').find('div.slideContainer:first').appendTo(slideshow) 
  $(this).siblings('.slideCount').text(count+'/'+slides)
}
if(count===slides){$(this).hide()}else{$(this).parent().find('div.prevSlide').show()}
});

$('.prevSlide').click(function (e){
var count=parseInt($(this).siblings('.slideCount').text().slice(0,-2))
var slideshow=$(this).parents('div.post-container').find('.slideshow')
var slides = $(slideshow).children().length;
if(count===1){e.preventDefault()}else{
  count--
  $(this).parents('div.post-container').find('div.slideContainer:last').prependTo(slideshow) 
  $(this).siblings('.slideCount').text(count+'/'+slides)
} 
if(count===1){$(this).hide()}else{$(this).parent().find('div.nextSlide').show()} 
});
```

And here's the JSFiddle with all the moving parts: http://jsfiddle.net/B4rqz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set height of children you need to set height of the parent too.

```
var maxheight = 0;
$('.slideshow').each(function() {
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        maxheight = ($(this).height() > maxheight ? $(this).height() : maxheight);
        console.log(maxheight);
    })
    $(this).height(maxheight).children().height(maxheight);
    console.log('Final:' + maxheight);
    maxheight = 0;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use deferred objects

**$(this).children().height(maxheight)** may execute before each loop ends as javascript is asynchronous

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with this method.

Comment: Was going through the code . In your case final max height value is 781 . But value added to you div is 801 . ie 20 more than 801

if you hard code a max height of 50 , then height of your div will be changed to 70 . Is there any code you have for incrementing ?